# how to use typeclass in `type` keyword?

Tags: haskell

I have a function

`logger :: ToJSON a => String -> a -> IO ()`

I'd like to make an alias for this type signature

```
type Logger = ToJSON a => String -> a -> IO ()
```

such that I can make more functions with the same type signature:

```
logger :: Logger

simpleLogger :: Logger
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
    • Illegal qualified type: ToJSON a => String -> a -> IO ()
      Perhaps you intended to use RankNTypes or Rank2Types
    • In the type synonym declaration for ‘Logger’
```

Comment: GHC just told you the answer. Use `{-# language RankNTypes #-}` at the top of the file, or `-XRankNTypes` on the GHCi command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC requires the `RankNTypes` extension to allow types with constraints to appear

1. In the definition of a type synonym:

   ```
   type A x = C x => x -> Y
   ```
2. In a field of a newtype or datatype declaration, or

   ```
   newtype B x = B (C x => x -> Y)
   data D x = D (C x => x -> Y)
   ```
3. On the left-hand side of an arrow.

   ```
   f :: (C x => x -> Y) -> Z
   ```

This may seem a bit surprising (it did to me), since these types are all actually rank-1. However, I have been told that the inference requirements of these types are actually quite similar to those of higher-rank types. In both cases, there's an argument that may need to be inferred. In the case of a higher-rank type, that is a type argument. In the case of a constrained type, that is a dictionary argument.

If you are writing a Haskell module, add

```
{-# language RankNTypes #-}
```

to the very top of the source file (before the `module` line). If you are using GHCi, either run

```
ghci -XRankNTypes
```

or type

```
:set -XRankNTypes
```

at the GHCi prompt.